# Pool DbContext with singleton dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I'm using the following [`DbContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext) implementation.

```cs
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IDateTimeOffset? _dateTime;

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public MyDbContext(
        DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options,
        IDateTimeOffset dateTime)
        : base(options)
    {
        _dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    // entities

    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        // set CreatedAt to DateTime.Now for all new entries
        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<AuditableEntity>())
        {
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                entry.Entity.CreatedAt = _dateTime!.Now;
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

The class has a dependency on `IDateTimeOffset` which is a simple wrapper around the static methods of [`DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset) that allows me to test the [`SaveChangesAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.savechangesasync#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContext_SaveChangesAsync_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) method.

```cs
interface IDateTimeOffset { DateTimeOffset Now { get; } }
class MachineDateTimeOffset : IDateTimeOffset { public DateTimeOffset Now => DateTimeOffset.Now; }
```

Now, let's assume we are in a high traffic scenario where creating a `DbContext` for each request puts too much pressure on the GC and that [`AddDbContextPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontextpool) would solve that issue. Using that method will throw a `System.InvalidOperationException: The DbContext of type 'MyDbContext' cannot be pooled because it does not have a single public constructor accepting a single parameter of type DbContextOptions` because `MyDbContext` has two constructors including one with two parameters. Sharing and reusing `IDateTimeOffset` in different requests is not an issue because it's a singleton so is there a way do that?

Comment: A DbContext for each request isn't supposed to be expensive.`AddDbContextPool` is meant to ease GC, memory allocations for high traffic scenarios but *doesn't* change DbContext's lifecycle - a clean instance is injected for each request and all changes are discarded unless explicitly saved at the end. Why do you assume DbContext creation is expensive?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use triggers to update the audit columns? If you have a high traffic scenario, it's far better to let the database perform batched updates than having the ORM perform them one by one.

Comment: You haven't explained why you think the DbContext creation is expensive yet. It's not - not unless you have StackOverflow-like traffic. If you have performance issues, post questions about them instead of assuming DbContext is expensive. Have you added all database tables as entities in a single DbContext perhaps? That's *not* a good design - a DbContext should only contain the entities needed for one scenario. In DDD terms you'd say you need a *different* DbContext per bounded context/use case

Comment: As for the specific error, pass your `IDateTimeOffse` wrapper as part of the `DbContextOptions`, not as a separate property. You can add your own option extensions with [DbContextOptions.WithExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptions-1.withextension?view=efcore-3.1). Again though, all the problems start from the assumption that DbContext is expensive, and that you need to update audit properties in the DbContext

Answer (score 1):

> Sharing and reusing IDateTimeOffset in different requests is not an issue because it's a singleton so is there a way do that?

Then just make it static.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public static IDateTimeOffset _dateTime;
```

And set it at startup.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer what `IDateTimeOffset` is. It's a wrapper around the **static** methods of `DateTimeOffset`. So yes I could directly call `DateTimeOffset.Now` in `MyDbContext.SaveChangesAsync` but that would make the testing of this method very difficult.

Comment: I don't see how it makes a difference.  It's a singleton service so just give your DbContext a static reference to it.